# PHP Connect to MSSQL From Both Linux and Windows

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, windows

I am using a linux build server (http://circleci.com) for auto builds and testing; however i need to connect to a MSSQL server. I can develop on windows fine and connect using the MS php SQLSVR drivers, but i cannot connect on the Linux build server as the drivers are windows only.

My Question is this: is there a single way to connect to MSSQL server via php for both windows and linux? tried odbc but then you need bdlib and FreeTDS on linux - this would constitute a code change thus meaning the tests are not 100%, for example on windows environment it would use `odbc:{SQL Server}` and on linux it would be `odbc:FreeTDS`

It just doesn't seem right to have a check to see what system is being used and then choose the corresponding db connection string.

I am using PHP 5.5.1

Comment: It might be better termed as a configuration change.

Comment: sorry, not sure what you mean?

Comment: If the connection strings are in a configuration file (and that's a better idea than putting directly into the code) then it's just a matter of changing the configuation file - so it's a configuration change

Comment: ah i get you, but as i though with the answer below it seems there would be external configuration changes as well. Im using symfony2 so was just using their approach, but that is a good idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not a single way however it would be trivial to do something like this:

```
if ('Linux' === PHP_OS){
    $pdo = new PDO("dblib:dbname=$database_name;host=$database_server", $username, $password);
}else{
    // $pdo = whatever you're using on your Windows box now.
}
```

You will need to set up your odbc.ini, odbcinst.ini and freetds.conf files on the Linux server as well.

Comment: Hi Thanks for this. just as I thought. However would you need to setup odbc.ini, odbcinst.ini and freetds.conf files every time? bearing in mind that the build server is provisioned from AWS and is fresh each time..

Comment: If it's fresh every time then yes, you would also have to set up those configuration files every time. When you say "fresh" I'm assuming it's a barebones Linux installation and that would mean you would also have to install the DBLib and FreeTDS software as well each time. You could write a BASH script to do these tasks and make it part of your process: 1) provision instance, 2) run script that installs software and updates config files, 3) run the builds/tests you're currently running.